# How to output a hex value but not as a string or int in Python?

Tags: python, hex

I have a function (not my own) that needs a hex value in the format 0x****** for a color value. The function that I have takes RGB values and converts them into hex, but outputs it as a string. Is there a way to take that string and evaluate it as a hex value?

I have tried changing the hex value into an integer but the function doesn't seem to accept integers.

This is the function I have that takes RGB values and converts it into hex.

```py
def decToHexa(n): 
 
    # char array to store hexadecimal number 
    hexaDeciNum = ['0'] * 100
 
    # Counter for hexadecimal number array 
    i = 0
     
    while (n != 0): 
 
        # Temporary variable to store remainder 
        temp = 0
 
        # Storing remainder in temp variable. 
        temp = n % 16
 
        # Check if temp < 10 
        if (temp < 10): 
            hexaDeciNum[i] = chr(temp + 48)
            i = i + 1
 
        else: 
            hexaDeciNum[i] = chr(temp + 55)
            i = i + 1
 
        n = int(n / 16)
 
    hexCode = ""
    if (i == 2):
        hexCode = hexCode + hexaDeciNum[0] 
        hexCode = hexCode + hexaDeciNum[1] 
 
    elif (i == 1): 
        hexCode = "0"
        hexCode = hexCode + hexaDeciNum[0]
 
    elif (i == 0):
        hexCode = "00"
 
    # Return the equivalent 
    # hexadecimal color code 
    return hexCode
 
# Function to convert the 
# RGB code to Hex color code 
def convertRGBtoHex(R, G, B): 
 
    if ((R >= 0 and R <= 255) and
        (G >= 0 and G <= 255) and
        (B >= 0 and B <= 255)): 
 
        hexCode = "0x"; 
        hexCode = hexCode + decToHexa(R)
        hexCode = hexCode + decToHexa(G) 
        hexCode = hexCode + decToHexa(B) 
        return hexCode
 
    # The hex color code doesn't exist 
    else:
        return "-1"
```

This is where the value is being used:

```py
def appendCharacter(self,ch,x,y,r,g,b):
        idx = self.numChars
        M = self.metrics[ch]
        self.textData[idx].screenXY = (x << 16) | y
        self.textData[idx].atlasXY = (M["x"]<<16) | M["y"]
        self.textData[idx].ascentDescentWidthLeftBearing = (
                (M["ascent"]<<24)   |
                (M["descent"]<<16)  |
                (M["width"]<<8)     |
                (M["leftbearing"]+128)      #make positive
        )
        self.textData[idx].color = int(convertRGBtoHex(r, g, b).lower(), 0)
        self.numChars+=1
```

I wish that I could give more information than this but most of the code that I have was provided by my professor so I have little knowledge of how it all works together.

Comment: What do you mean by "not as a string"? The concepts of decimal and hex only make sense when formatting numbers as text.

Comment: @Barmar The function I'm using seems to interpret "0x******" as a string and not as a value. I'm sorry that I don't understand the problem enough to explain it properly.

Comment: If you put it in quotes then it's a string. Call the function without quotes. `func(0x12345)` and it will get a number.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you really need with so few details in the question.

Comment: Maybe you just need the hex string without `0x` at the beginning? Your question is extremely unclear without the details of the function you're calling.

Comment: Can you post the function definition or its documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your entire `decToHexa` function with just this

```
#08x = (0) pad (8) positions he(x)adecimal
hxd = f'0x{n:08x}'
```

To convert back to int

```
#convert to int using base 16
i = int(hxd, 16)
```

Something to note: It seems like you assume it has to be in hex format to use bit-shifting. You can bit-shift any int. Hexadecimal format is just a way for you to easily represent a numeric concept. It's the actual number you are bit-shifting, not the conceptual representation. In other words, you don't have to convert it to hexadecimal, at all, unless something you are using is expecting that format (ie. generally RGBA values).

Answer (score 2):

If your function specifically requires a hex value in the format 0x****** and does not accept integers, you can keep the value as an integer but format it as a hex string with the "0x" prefix. Here's how you can do that:

```
# Convert your RGB values to an integer (e.g., 0x33FF99)
rgb_int = (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue

# Format it as a hex string with the "0x" prefix
formatted_hex = f"0x{rgb_int:06X}"
```

Red, green, and blue represent your RGB values (each in the range 0-255).

rgb_int is constructed by shifting and combining these values into a single integer in the format 0xRRGGBB.

f"0x{rgb_int:06X}" formats rgb_int as a string with the "0x" prefix and at least 6 characters, so it follows the format 0x******.

Try using rgb_int as a argument in your function.

Comment: They say they don't want a string, so I suspect they actually need `rgb_int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the int() method in python to convert the string to hex.
Something like this:

```
hex_value = int("the returned hex string", 16)
```

the second argument is the base of the result(hex)
That will give you the value as hex

Comment: Would hex_value be an actual value or would it be a string formatted as a hex value? Also I need it to be as a hex value and not an integer that represents a hex value.

Comment: Now that I look at it, I've tried doing that before, but it converts it into an int which the function (for some reason) doesn't work properly with.

Comment: The int() method returns a value with the specified base(second parameter of the int() method). The value should be a hex but most likely not in the format you need.